# Como realizar un bucle for dentro de un <h:dataTable> en JSF

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Estoy realizando un listado con una tabla en JSF, es realmente sencillo llevarlo a cabo con la etiqueta `<h:dataTable>`, pero necesito hacer un bucle dentro de la tabla para poder filtrar ciertos datos de otra lista.
Mi codigo sigue la siguiente estructura.

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{usrBean.usuarios}" var="u"
                    styleClass="table table-hover"
                    headerClass="order-table-header"
                    rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
                        >

                    <h:column>
                        <!-- column header -->
                        <f:facet name="header">DNI</f:facet>
                        <!-- row record -->
                        #{u.idUsr}
                    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Quisiera saber si lo que pretendo es posible o debo hacer todos los filtros en el javaBean y luego pasarlo "limpio" hacia el xhtml.

Comment: En mi opinión lo más limpio es que filtres en el backing bean, no en el código xhtml.

Comment: al final probablemente haga eso, solamente preguntaba por curiosidad. :D